# How to create a new view that classifies each job based on the latest task code it has completed?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database

I have some data that I need to classify into various stages depending on the TaskCode that has an EndDate that is highest up in the hierarchy. Here the EndDate signifies the date that the TaskCode was completed. There are 8 TaskCodes that are relevant and signify that a Stage should be assigned to that job though there are dozens of TaskCodes that are irrelevant.

I have already written a program in Python that performs this task but must now complete it in SQL. The logic behind it in Python is as follows with "data" being the dataset described above and show as an example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['JobNumber', 'Stage'])
for count, value in enumerate(data['JobNumber']):
  job = data[data['JobNumber'] == i]
  
  if job['TaskCode'].isin(052300):
    if job[job['CostCode'] == 052300]['ActualEndDate'].notna().all()
      df.loc[count, 'Stage'] = 'Final'
            continue

  if job['TaskCode'].isin(048000):
    if job[job['CostCode'] == 052300]['ActualEndDate'].notna().all()
      df.loc[count, 'Stage'] = 'Middle'
            continue
```

The code continues for each task that signifies a stage until at the end it provides a catch all "else:" statement that assigns all jobs that did not have any of the task codes.

There are two pieces I find particularly tricky: 1) there are cases where a job may have duplicates of a TaskCode that signal a stage but only one of them has an EndDate. In these cases we should not classify this job at the corresponding TaskCode stage as all duplicates must also have an EndDate. 2) The actual EndDate value is not important with respect to how we classify the data. It should move down a hierarchy of TaskCodes that then see if all values of that TaskCode for a specific job have non Null values. If that is the case then assign a stage.

I am not strong at SQL and have rarely used it outside of simple queries to retrieve data. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

| JobNumber | EndDate | TaskCode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 01/12/2022 | 052300 |
| 99999 | NULL | 048000 |
| 23780 | 11/24/2021 | 789010 |
| 12345 | NULL | 052300 |

Expected result table:

| JobNumber | Stage |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | Final |
| 99999 | Start |
| 23780 | Middle |

Edit: My current query of -

```
SELECT JT.JobNumber,
CASE WHEN TaskCode = '456787' AND EndDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'Final'
     WHEN CostCode = '345881' AND EndDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'Interior'
     WHEN TaskCode = '986482' AND EndDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'Trim'
     WHEN TaskCode = '456480' AND EndDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'Sheetrock'
     WHEN TaskCode = '548638' AND EndDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'Mechanicals'
     WHEN TaskCode = '001001' AND EndDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'Cornice'
     WHEN TaskCode = '010840' AND EndDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'Frame'
     WHEN TaskCode = '049100' AND EndDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'Frame'
     ELSE 'Slab' END AS Stage
FROM [Task] AS JT
INNER JOIN [Jobs] AS CJ ON JT.JobNumber = CJ.JobNumber
```

is close to what I am looking for. However, the result of this returns the job with a stage classification for every task that job has (many duplicates of the same JobNumber). My desired result is a unique JobNumber column with one classification for the stage in which the TaskCode of the highest priority is satisfied (the highest up in the CASE statement) for each job.

Comment: So should the results include *all* tasks, or only ones with an EndDate? What do the expected results look like for the sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on whether the expected results should include *all* tasks or only "completed" tasks. For the moment, let's assume only "completed" tasks.

**Sample Data:**

```
JobNumber | EndDate    | TaskCode
--------: | :--------- | :-------
    12345 | 2022-01-12 | 052300  
    99999 | null       | 048000  
    23780 | 2021-11-24 | 789010  
    12345 | null       | 052300  
    45678 | 2022-01-12 | 048000  
    45678 | 2022-01-01 | 052300  -- silly demo that latest date takes precedence
```

Start by finding "Completed" tasks

```
SELECT * 
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  EndDate IS NOT NULL
```

**Results:**

```
JobNumber | EndDate    | TaskCode
--------: | :--------- | :-------
    12345 | 2022-01-12 | 052300  
    23780 | 2021-11-24 | 789010  
    45678 | 2022-01-12 | 048000  
    45678 | 2022-01-01 | 052300
```

Then use a window function to assign a [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) by JobNumber grouping, sorting by the most recent EndDate first. Then grab records with row number = 1

```
;WITH cte AS (
   SELECT JobNumber
          , EndDate
          , TaskCode
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JobNumber ORDER BY EndDate DESC) AS RowNum
   FROM  YourTable
   WHERE EndDate IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT JobNumber
       , EndDate
       , TaskCode
       , RowNum
FROM   cte
WHERE  RowNum = 1
```

**Results:**

```
JobNumber | EndDate    | TaskCode | RowNum
--------: | :--------- | :------- | -----:
    12345 | 2022-01-12 | 052300   |      1
    23780 | 2021-11-24 | 789010   |      1
    45678 | 2022-01-12 | 048000   |      1
```

Finally, add a [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to determine the "Stage" of each Job

```
;WITH cte AS (
   SELECT JobNumber
          , EndDate
          , TaskCode
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JobNumber ORDER BY EndDate DESC) AS RowNum
   FROM  YourTable
   WHERE EndDate IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT JobNumber
       , EndDate
       , TaskCode
       , CONVERT(VARCHAR(50) 
            , CASE TaskCode 
                   WHEN '052300' THEN 'Final'
                   WHEN '048000' THEN 'Middle'
                   -- ... more codes ... 
                   ELSE 'CATCH_ALL_DEFAULT_HERE'
              END
           ) AS Stage
FROM   cte
WHERE  RowNum = 1
```

**Results:**

```
JobNumber | EndDate    | TaskCode | Stage                 
--------: | :--------- | :------- | :---------------------
    12345 | 2022-01-12 | 052300   | Final                 
    23780 | 2021-11-24 | 789010   | CATCH_ALL_DEFAULT_HERE
    45678 | 2022-01-12 | 048000   | Middle
```

demo [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d15cb53394a9466689f2b129d47d173b)

---

**Update 2022-03-04**

To retrieve the highest priority TaskCode that's completed, either use a mapping table or create one on-the-fly with a VALUES() clause. The table should contain the task code, its priority, and the stage it maps to.

Use an [OUTER JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) to ensure the results include all JobNumbers, even those without a relevant TaskCode. Then use ROW_NUMBER() as before. However, instead of sorting by date, sort by tasks *with* a relevant TaskCode first, those without one second. Then sort by the highest priority number and grab the first record.

```
; WITH cte AS (
   SELECT t.JobNumber
          , t.EndDate
          , t.TaskCode
          , tc.TaskPriority
          , tc.TaskStage
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
              PARTITION BY t.JobNumber 
              ORDER BY 
                -- sort completed tasks with a relevant code first
                CASE WHEN t.EndDate IS NOT NULL AND tc.TaskPriority IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                     ELSE 2
                END
                -- sort by actual priority
                , tc.TaskPriority ASC
          ) AS RowNum
   FROM  YourTable t LEFT JOIN 
            (
               VALUES 
                 (1, '456787', 'Final')
                 , (2,'345881', 'Interior')
                 , (3, '986482', 'Trim')
                 , (4, '456480', 'Sheetrock')
                 , (5, '548638', 'Mechanicals')
                 , (6, '001001', 'Cornice')
                 , (7, '010840',  'Frame')
                 , (8, '049100',  'Frame')            
            ) tc(TaskPriority,TaskCode,TaskStage)
            ON tc.TaskCode = t.TaskCode
)
SELECT JobNumber
       , ISNULL(TaskStage, 'CATCH_ALL') AS TaskStage
FROM   cte
WHERE  RowNum = 1
;
```

**Sample:**

```
JobNumber | EndDate    | TaskCode  
--------: | :--------- | :---------
    12345 | 2022-01-12 | 986482    
    99999 | null       | IRRELEVANT
    77777 | null       | IRRELEVANT
    77777 | 2021-11-15 | 001001    
    88888 | null       | 456480    
    23780 | 2021-11-24 | 789010    
    12345 | null       | 052300    
    45678 | 2022-01-12 | 001001    
    45678 | 2022-01-01 | 052300
```

**Results:**

```
JobNumber | TaskStage
--------: | :--------
    12345 | Trim     
    23780 | CATCH_ALL -- because 789010 is not a relevant code
    45678 | Cornice  
    77777 | Cornice  
    88888 | Sheetrock
    99999 | CATCH_ALL
```

Comment: I really appreciate the response @SOS as this is getting close to what I am looking for and I learned new techniques from your solution. The remaining issue is that the actual date within the EndDate is not relevant. Instead of looking for the most recent EndDate I am looking for the TaskCode that is highest up in the hierarchy to do the classification, and if a TaskCode is not present then it goes down to the next one. The EndDate portion must just be non Null for all pairs of a JobNumber and TaskCode. I edited my question for clarity and added an example result table.

Comment: 1) Should the results *only* include jobs that have one of those 8 codes (even if the date is null)? For example, if job 99999 *only* had entries for codes `IRRELEVANT1` and `IRRELEVANT2` should it be included in the results?  2) What are the expected results if a job has an entry for multiple codes in your list? Which one should be used for classification - still the highest priority code - or the one with the most recent date, if any?

Comment: Tbh it would help to have a few edge cases in the sample data and expected results. So we can see why the expected result for a job is X of Y, or job X should be included but not job Y.

Comment: If Job 999999 only had entries for irrelevant codes then it would be classified within the catch all stage. When a job has multiple codes it should be assigned the one with the highest priority. I will post an edit right now showing my current query that I believe is very close to what I need.

Comment: See updated query.  I kept the single table example so it makes more sense to anyone looking at the samples in the OP.